# Atiyah-Macdonalds Exercise 5.1

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm attempting Atiyah-Macdonalds Exercise 5.1:

> Let $f: A \to B$ be an integral homomorphism of rings.
>               Show that $f^{\ast}: \text{Spec}(B) \to \text{Spec}(A)$ is a closed mapping,
>               i.e. that it maps closed sets to closed sets.
>               (This is a geometrical equivalent of (5.10)).

Here $f$ being integral means that $B$ is integral over $f(A)$.
We want to show that for any closed subset $C \subset \text{Spec}(B)$,
$f^{\ast}(C) = \{f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) | \mathfrak{p}) \in C \}$ is closed.

I'm quite stuck at the beginning, in particular I'm not sure how to make connections between integral and the topology on spectrum of an ring.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I presume 5.10 is a theorem or something. What does it say?

Comment: There are many online solutions to the exercises in this book. I find [this text](http://www.math.toronto.edu/jcarlson/intro_comm_alg(Palatino).pdf) outstanding. Other links are given [here](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Pierre-Yves.Gaillard/DIVERS/Atiyah_MacDonald_b/).